# C++ Substitute function

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm having some problems with the following code:

```
/* replace c1 with c2 in s, returning s */
char *substitute(char *s, char c1, char c2)
{
    char *r = s;
    if (s == 0) return 0;
    for (; *s; ++s)
        if (*s == c1) *s = c2;
    return r;
}

void substitute(char c1, char c2);

int main()
{
    string s = "apples";
    char a;
    char b;

    cout << "Before swap of Char : " << s << endl;

    *substitute(&a, &b);

    cout << "After swap of Char : " << s << endl;

    system("pause");
}
```

The code above should replace any occurrences of `char1` in the string with `char2`. I think I have the function down right but calling it is a bit of an issue as the `Substitute` part in main is showing errors.

My question is how do I continue on from here and call the function in main?

EDIT:
I've read through the answers that have been given but I'm still confused on what to do as I'm a beginner..

EDIT Again:
I've worked it out! :)

Comment: There's so many problems with this... just use `std::string::replace`.

Comment: `substitute` has three arguments passing only `two`?

Comment: The arguments and the return type in the declaration and definition of `substitute` do not match. Why is the function declared after its definition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the issues I see with the code:

1. **`substitute()` should get 3 arguments**, `char*,char,char`, or if you have later a function `substitute(char,char)`. However, you are sending `char*,char*` to it, so the compiler doesn't know what function to invoke (unless you have another function with this signature which is not showed here). This is the reason for the *compile time error*
2. **You are trying to modify a *string literal***, it *could* create a run time error, if you will fix the compile time error. Note that the string "apples" should not be modified, as it is string literal. You will need to copy it and then change it. The exact behavior of modifying it is undefined, as pointed by @6502 (reference on comments)
3. **Your code is poorly idented** (though the edit fixed this issue).
4. `a,b` are not initialized and contain 'junk' values.

Comment: Modifying a literal doesn't create a run time error, it's undefined behaviour.

Comment: @6502 I think I read somewhere that in C++ it is defined and causes an error, and UB only on C, could be wrong though, can you ref me please to the source?

Comment: N3690, page 29 top, point 12: "Whether all string literals are distinct (that is, are stored in nonoverlapping objects) is implementation-defined. The effect of attempting to modify a string literal is undefined."

Answer (score 1):

If you are in c++(11), you might want to use the standard library and the language facilities:

```
 std::string input = "apples";
 const char from='a';
 const char to='b';
 std::for_each(input.begin(),input.end(),
  [&](char& current) {
   if(current==from)
    current=to;
 });
```

or even more concise

```
for (char& current : input) {
   if(current==from)
     current=to;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're passing two arguments while your function requires 3, plus that the function itself will not work as intended.

Also, on a side note, use cin.get() instead of system("pause");

Just use the method replace of the string class.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize **a** and **b** then call the substitute method as `substitute(s,&a, &b);`

Remove the method prototype `void substitute(char c1, char c2);`as you don't need it.

Comment: remove void substitute(char,char) if you are not using it.

Comment: as you have two substitute methods, you are getting that error, also you didn't define substitute(char, char), better remove it if you are not using it, then you can use substitute(s,&a,&b).

Comment: also dont forget to initialize characters a and b.

Answer (score 0):

As is, you can call the function like this:

```
char a = 's', b='t';
char s[] = "some string";
s = substitute(s, a, b);
```

The second and third argument are not pointers, so you can just pass `a` and `b`, you don't have to pass `&a` or `&b`.

Note that since you're simply modifying the string in the first argument, there's really no reason to assign it to anything. `substitute(a, b);` would do exactly the same as `s = substitute(s, a, b);`.

And if you don't have to use your return value, there's really no reason to return it in the first place. You can change your function to this:

```
/* replace c1 with c2 in s, returning s */
void substitute(char *s, char c1, char c2)
{
    if (s == 0) return;
    for (; *s; ++s)
        if (*s == c1) *s = c2;
}
```

Comment: notice that the first argument to `substitute()` is not a `char *`, but rather it's a string... further complicating things.

Comment: Do you know that modifying a literal is forbidden?